# Maximum number of topic subscription in mqtt?

Tags: mqtt

In mqtt, is there any limitation or performance issue on the maximum number of topic that a client  can subscribe ?

Let say i have posted 1000 comment on 1000 post. and for each new comment on any of these post i should be notified so to do this i want to subscribe to all 1000 topic. Is that a good solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is entirely dependant on the following variables

1. The number of clients
2. The number of messages per topic
3. The number of clients subscribed to each topic
4. The size of the machine running the broker

   There is no generic answer to this, you will have to test and find out

Comment: Does subscribing to many topic occupy more memory on client side also e.g in case of mobile app using paho js client ?

Comment: No, as there client doesn't even keep the list of topics it's subscribed to

Answer (score 7):

Instead of subscribing to 1000 different topics, try to create a nested topic structure.

For example:

```
forum1/posts/1456/comments/1
forum1/posts/1456/comments/2
forum1/posts/1456/comments/3
forum2/posts/54/comments/24
```

Then you can subscribe using a wildcard:

```
// get all comments about post 1456
client.subscribe("forum1/posts/1456/#");
```

this will receive all comments on post with id 1456.
MQTT has two wildcards: **#** matches any depth, while **+** matches one level only.

```
// get first comment of any post
client.subscribe("forum1/posts/+/comments/1");
```

Take a look at [the excellent topic & best practices](http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-5-mqtt-topics-best-practices) article on HiveMQ blog for further reference.